# Azure Location Based Services support in China?

Tags: azure-maps

According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-location-based-services-public-preview/, Azure location-based services public preview on 11/28/2017 which is good, as a China developer, I'd like to know if it's supporting China map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Location Based Services will not be available if your current IP address is in below countries.

- China
- India
- Pakistan
- Argentina
- Morocco
- South Korea.

However we have maps of those countries available. If your current IP address is not in China you will be able to access China map.

Comment: any update on this?  This is a deal breaker for us.... we rely so heavily on Azure, but we have a huge presence in China and India.  Would like to utilize these services.

Comment: Why is it not available in China?